# Do I have to pay to get Google custom search in my app?

Tags: ios, google-custom-search

Recently I decided to take advantage of Google custom search engine and embed it inside my iPhone application. I scoped my search engine to number of websites to search in, I got both KEY&cx and added them to my code, every thing works as expected, but after several successful search queries I can no longer receive any results - I get an empty array containing the following message:

> "code": 403,
>   "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"

As I know, every user of my application has a set of search attempts, 100 per day, if he exceeded that limit he has to wait 24 hour to be able to search again for another 100 queries. But the case here is that I no longer have the ability to search at all!

If I hit my quota I have to wait for the next day? Am I wrong?

Comment: No you don't until you cross the limit, check out more details with complete process here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600

Answer (score 1):

If you don't sign up for billing you are capped at 100 queries per day. Don't confuse the wording *per user*. You or rather your API key is the user therefore your overall usage is tied to this limit.

> **Free quota**
>
> Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day.
>
> **Paid Usage**
>
> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day. If you need additional quota, please request additional quota from the console.

Source: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing

Answer (score 0):

I got same error too， last, I found the real reason:

miss 'key' parameter