# Implementing Google custom search API in iOS

Tags: ios, json, google-custom-search

I went through several links in order to find the proper steps to implement google customsearchapi in an ios application and spent about 6-7 hours in that process.

**Links:**

- https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction
- http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list?q=a&_h=1&
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/hT2fnfErVwo
- [Google Custom Search: 403 error in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212412/google-custom-search-403-error-in-ios)
- [And Father of all](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20implement%20google%20custom%20search%20api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=u6ZtVM7YG6TM8geh04CYBw)

All these provide bits and peaces of formation. Is there any place to have a summarize, precise info that can help to implement the custom search in an iOS application?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Brief Step of the process:**

1. Create a Google account (ignore if you have one)
2. You may found some piece of information related to pricing at the bottom of [this page helpful](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)(you can ignore this too)
3. Create a project and generate the API key
4. Go to [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and create a project
5. After the project is created, click on it to go to its detail.
6. On the left bar under the Auth&API segment, click on APIs.
7. Now you'll find [CustomSearchAPI](https://console.developers.google.com/project/gothic-standard-770/apiui/apiview/customsearch) link in the Browse APIs section (as it is not activated by default), turn it on by clicking on the button at right.
8. Now click on Credentials, just below the APIs option
9. On this page under "Public API Access" click on Create New Key Button, for now, choose the browser key(as at first we wanna test it on the browser), create it, and leave it, as it is for now.
10. Create [Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse)
11. Now on the new tab, open [Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse) page. On this page click on Create a custom search engine, button
12. That will lead you to [create a new search engine page](https://www.google.com/cse/create/new), here give your domain name in the "Sites to search" field. (If you don't have one no worries, give anything, that has www. at the start and .com in the end)
13. Fill in the name, if it hasn't pick one already, then click on create.
14. So you got a jumping robot to congratulate you? ;) Yeah, that's it. On this page step up to "Modify your search engine", by clicking on, "Control Panel" button
15. There you are, now turn on the Image Search, (if you want to)
16. Also in the "Sites to search" section, select, "Search the entire web but emphasize on the included item", instead of, the default one, which is "Search only included site"
17. That is it, at the bottom of this page click on update. And then come back to the middle of the page and under the "Detail" title, click on Search engine ID, copy the Id, paste it somewhere.
18. Search, [using get request](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=a&key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&cx=%7BSEARCH_ENGINE_KEY%7D):
19. To make a get request use [this request URL](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=a&key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&cx=%7BSEARCH_ENGINE_KEY%7D)
20. In it replace, {API_KEY} which you have created under "Create a project and generate API key" section
21. And replace {SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY} with the Search engine Id you just copy-pasted
    Call it with some different value, at query string, then 'a', [https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?**q=a**&key={API_KEY}&cx={SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?**q=a**&key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&cx=%7BSEARCH_ENGINE_KEY%7D) change a with anything you wanna search you must have got the beautiful JSON of search result
22. Other Stuff
23. If you wanna see the request status, go back to your project page, that how many requests placed, how many of those failed, etc. Click on the overview and you will get the graph for that, love you google
24. If you have trouble with JSON, here are some links at your service,

    1. What is JSON [1](http://www.json.org/), [2](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)?
    2. Use JSON in [ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).
    3. Use JSON in [android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944).

Comment: Thank You. It Helped A Lot !

Comment: it worked mann thanks a lott , i want to get al the images with that keyword. can u help?

Comment: @KunalGupta There is always a max response cap for any search keyword, so getting all images for a keyword will be technically not possible with this APIs.

Comment: but the response is totally different in case of getting from API and using google image search in browser

Comment: Yeah. Since they charge for the API and limiting the response in necessary in case some one abuse there response. That is why they have this limit.

Comment: error =     {
        code = 400;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = usageLimits;
                message = "Bad Request";
                reason = keyInvalid;
            }
        );
        message = "Bad Request";
    };  why do i get this reponse ??

Comment: found it , issue was percentage mark , great explanation

Comment: @Mr.G Great, Glad it helped!

Comment: Both services Custom Search Engine and Google Site Search will shut down on April 1st 2018. Any other alternatives ? @rptwsthi

Comment: @OhadM I am not aware of that right now, will check and let you know, if I  find something.

Comment: This is working fine on simulator..but not working on iphone devices..can you help??

Comment: I am not sure, can you please check if internet connection is working fine on your device.

Answer (score 1):

The following provide implementation in **Swift 4**, of `"GET"` request from `google custom search engine`,

```
let apiKey = "Your api key here"
let bundleId = "com.Your uniqueBundleId here"
let searchEngineId = "Your searchEngine here"
let serverAddress = String(format: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=%@&cx=%@&key=%@","Your query here" ,searchEngineId, apiKey)


let url = serverAddress.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let finalUrl = URL(string: url!)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: finalUrl!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue(bundleId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

let session = URLSession.shared

let datatask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    do{
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print("asyncResult\(jsonResult)")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
datatask.resume()
```