# How to use the new Google Search API?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, api, google-custom-search

I'm making an application that will get any Disney links in Google for the father of my cousin. The Google Search API is no longer available. It is, but it's another version, and I don't know how to work with it.

```
Dim search As New GwebSearchClient("")
Dim results As IList(Of IWebResult) = search.Search("Disney Kids", 64, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
For Each result As IWebResult In results
    ListBox1.Items.Add(result.Url)
Next
```

The old API:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-for-dotnet/downloads

The new API which I get an error on Visual Studio saying:

> [response status:403] The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please
>   migrate to the Google Custom Search API
>   (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

How can I do this?

Comment: here is a guide with `C#`, Should be easy to translate.http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-use-google-custom-search-api/comment-page-1/

Comment: Using search API is platform independent as it returns response in JSON, you can learn basic setup and other details here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600.

Comment: "father of my cousin" = "uncle" nicht wahr?