# How To Make BOT In Google

Tags: vb.net, bots, google-search, plagiarism-detection

I'm creating a program to detect plagiarism articles using VB.NET. In the program I created, I use google as a tool to detect it. Example there is a piece of article like this:

Computer is one of today's technology that is quite popular

So the algorithm that I use is, I enter the sentence into a google search by using the first two quotes and the end of the sentence. so i will search on google with keywords like this.
"Computer is one of today's technology that is quite popular"
If the search google, found there is a website that uses the sentence, it can be ascertained that the article is plagiarism.

However, my program has to check hundreds of articles. So it will automatically open google and search for many keywords in a short time. The program I created, opened google by using webbrowser.

Apparently, because the program I have to check hundreds of articles, then the webbrowser gradually raises an error like this:
[image]
Because indeed I'm making a bot for search on google.

Well, is there any suggestion to overcome / outsmart this problem?

This my code : (sorry, comments on my code are in Indonesian)

```
                Dim totallink As String = ""
                tempcek = tempstrline.Substring(start, selesai - start)

                'cek di google
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.co.id/search?q=%22" & tempcek & "%22")
                'proses menunggu webbrowser loading
                Dim sw As New Stopwatch
                sw.Start()
                Do Until sw.Elapsed.Seconds = 5
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Loop
                sw.Stop()
                sw.Reset()
                '------
                'cek pada source code browser 
                'pattern : </a></h3><div class="s">
                'pattern2 : href="
                Dim pattern As String = "</a></h3><div class=" & Chr(34) & "s" & Chr(34) & ">"
                Dim pattern2 As String = "href=" & Chr(34)
                If WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains(pattern) And Not WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.ToLower.Contains("tidak ditemukan") Then

                    Dim tempsc As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml
                    'mendapatkan semua link yang ada di pencarian google
                    While tempsc.IndexOf(pattern) > -1
                        tempsc = tempsc.Substring(tempsc.IndexOf(pattern) - 300)
                        Dim templink As String = tempsc.Substring(tempsc.IndexOf(pattern2) + 6)
                        templink = templink.Substring(0, templink.IndexOf(Chr(34)))
                        tempsc = tempsc.Substring(350)
                       webbrowser.contains(pattern) diatas
                        totallink &= templink & "."
                        hasil(idxhasil) = totallink & ";" & i & "," & tempcek

                    End While

                Else
                    'cek selanjutnya dengan kondisi sudah mentok string yang plagiasi 
                    idxhasil += 1
                    start = tempstrline.IndexOf(" ", selesai) + 1
                    hitungspasike4(selesai, tempstrline)

                End If
                'cek selanjutnya dengan kondisi string masih bisa dikembangkan lagi untuk dicek plagiasinya
                selesai = tempstrline.IndexOf(" ", selesai + 1)
```

Comment: Are you using google's search API? You didn't post any code so we don't really know how your program works.

Comment: sorry, I've added the above code

Comment: I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/7948962) should help you resolve your problem.